# Wrap title and sub title to next lines in pie amchart 3

Tags: angular6, amcharts

I am using pie amchart v3, and i am using **allLabels** property to display the title and subtitle. But the problem is that, title is not wrapping to the next line as shown below

[image]

How to Wrap the text "**TOP BUS TYPES: BUS TYPES**" to next line?
Below is my code.

```
 const chart = this.AmCharts.makeChart( "mychart", {
            "type": "pie",
            "theme": "light",
            "dataProvider": busvalue,
            "titleField": "title",
            "valueField": "value",
            "labelsEnabled": false,
            "radius": "40%",
            "innerRadius": "60%",
            "colorField": "color",
            "allLabels": [{
                "y": "48%",
                "align": "center",
                "size": 17,
                "bold": true,
                "text": 'TOP BUS TYPES: BUS TYPES',
                "color":'#000000'
              },{
                "y": "52%",
                "align": "center",
                "size": 12,
                "text": ''
                "color": '#000000
            }],
           ...
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any mechanism to automatically wrap free labels (`allLabels`) in amcharts v3. You have to insert your own newline characters as needed in your string, e.g. `"text": 'TOP BUS TYPES:\nBUS TYPES'`

```js
AmCharts.makeChart("mychart", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "title": "1",
    "value": 10
  }, {
    "title": "2",
    "value": 10
  }, {
    "title": "3",
    "value": 10
  }],
  "titleField": "title",
  "valueField": "value",
  "labelsEnabled": false,
  "radius": "40%",
  "innerRadius": "60%",
  "colorField": "color",
  "allLabels": [{
    "y": "48%",
    "align": "center",
    "size": 17,
    "bold": true,
    "text": 'TOP BUS TYPES:\nBUS TYPES',
    "color": '#000000'
  }, {
    "y": "52%",
    "align": "center",
    "size": 12,
    "text": '',
    "color": '#000000'
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="mychart" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
```